# Tap count when application is in background

Tags: iphone, ios, gesture, taps

Is it possible to count the number of Taps when an application is in background mode?

Comment: That's a quite simple answer :) No

Comment: when our application on background. user can tap anywhere .. i googling it. it is possible or not. so i ask here.. i thinks it's not possible

Comment: +1 for that who down vote me...thanks for down vote me.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible because taps are handled by the `UIResponder` class. It is the superclass of `UIApplication`, `UIView` and its subclasses (which include `UIWindow`), so there is no way to "globally" count the taps - you can do it only for your app, when it's active..